# how can a web application verify data from a data base

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jakarta-ee

I am new on JEE I want to create an authentication application that verifies the login and the password in a postgres data base through a servlet any help please

Comment: Please see the [help]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'll describe you the steps, you will have to code it

```
1/ get the login info
2/ do a select inside your database with the user info (select * from table where user = login AND password == password)
3.1/ if you get 0 result, your user doesn't exist or he doesn't provide the valids information
3.2/ if you get more than 1 result, you got a problem with your database (maybe your login isn't unique)
3.3/ if you got only one result, your user exist with this information !
```

Of course, you have to have a password stored with a sha1 + salt ;)